# SIGSEGV when searching through the (modified) bidirectional list

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a console game with shooting mechanism handled by modified bidirectional list:

tank.h:

```
typedef
struct Shoots
{
    struct Shoot* head;
    struct Shoot* tail;
}shootsList;

typedef
struct Shoot
{
    short coords[2];
    short vect;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;
    struct Shoot* next;
    struct Shoot* prev;
}shoot_t;
```

and in tank.cpp I have a procedure

```
void manageShoots(char arena[][35], char hitmap[][35])
{
    shoot_t* sht = shoots.head;
    while(sht->next != NULL) sht = sht->next; (...)
```

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
At C:...\TS\tank.cpp:46:
while(sht->next != NULL) sht = sht->next;

In main.cpp before using manageShoots I've initialised list:

```
shootsList shoots;
shoots->head = NULL;
shoots->tail = NULL;
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: we need the rest of your code: `next` to NULL?? and the malloc part when you allocate a new cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is empty i.e. shoots.head == NULL, sht->next causes SIGSEGV.
Loop should look like this:

```
while (sht != NULL)
{
    // do processing, if any
    sht = sht->next;
}
```